# Move a UIView based on the content offset for UIScrollView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, animation, drop-down-menu

I am trying to pull down a UIView (Like a Pull Down Menu) when the user scrolls below a Y-offset of 0.0 in the UITable View. If the user pulls down below -80.0 Y-Offset, then the PullDownMenu locks itself , until the User scrolls the other way.

My implementation for just the UITableView's ScrollView is as follows : [**lock:false** initially]

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if(isChangingOffset)
        return;
    if(resetDrag)
    {
        [self setScrollViewOffset:scrollView offsetTo:CGPointMake(0, -80.0)];
        resetDrag = false;
    }
    float xx = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
NSLog(@"Offset :%f",xx);
    if(xx - begginOffset > 0.0 && lock && !doneDragging)
    {
        offsetChange = xx - begginOffset;
        begginOffset = xx;
        lock = false;
        [self setScrollViewOffset:scrollView offsetTo:CGPointMake(0, -80.0)];
    }
    if(lock){
        [self setScrollViewOffset:scrollView offsetTo:CGPointMake(0, -80.0)];
    }
    if(xx <=-80.0)
    {
        [self setScrollViewOffset:scrollView offsetTo:CGPointMake(0, -80.0)];
        lock = true;
    }
}
```

**- (void)setScrollViewOffset:(UIScrollView *)scrollView offsetTo:(CGPoint)offset{**

```
- (void)setScrollViewOffset:(UIScrollView *)scrollView offsetTo:(CGPoint)offset{
    isChangingOffset = true;
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -80.0);
    isChangingOffset = false;
}
```

**-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView**

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    float x = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    begginOffset = x;
    doneDragging = false;
    if(lock){
        resetDrag = true;
    }
}
```

**-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    doneDragging = true;
}
```

Here is a working video of how it looks : [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzfsUcb6_jY)

The blue color is a UIView that I have added as a subview in the UITableView.

My problem is , I am trying to pull down a UIView,lets call it menuView (that is not a subview of the tableView) based on the UITableView's contentOffset. I could have simply added the menuView in the UITableView like I added the blue color view. But that is only accessible via the table, that is when I scroll to the top and drag it down. But I want the menuView to be 'pull-able' like the notification center at any time. 
On using the Y-contentOffset of scroll view, the menuview pull down animation is not smooth. And it stops midway or goes too low. It is jerky and not always the same. How can I implement this ?

Comment: I think is better to embed all in a `UIScrollView` is more simple and more fast to execute, you can set bouns up and down, pagination and more features, if you want i give you a sample code for the `UIScrollView`

Comment: A scrollView that contains UIView and a UITableView ?

Comment: A ScrollView is a View with scroll and can contain what you want inside, a other View, TableView, Buttons, Label, textField and more more, you can set for example a Scroll view Long 5000px and paginated to a 480 or 568 ;) ned code?

Comment: But how will that help me Create a pulldown menu like system ?

Comment: You can use the UiScrollView to a Puldown menu appear when tap a button, or take a look for pulldown menu in my answare i post you a link with example code

Answer (score 2):

Here the sample code for your `UIScrollView` :

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController: UIViewController {

    UIScrollView *scrollView;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize scrollView;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self scrollView];
    }

    - (void)scrollText{

        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
        scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    }
```

And iside you can put wat you want, from code or interface builder.

For a PullDownMenu you can see this GitHub:

[MBPullDownController](https://github.com/matej/MBPullDownController)

Hope this help you and simplify your code ;)

Comment: I think UITableView is already implements UIScrollView. Also this wont help me achieve the notification center like pulldown menu, or the pulldown menu similar to the one in the video. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: is probable you have to rebuild the app but I'am sure this http://vimeo.com/bukovinski/mbpulldowncontroller can help you, and the link on my answer MBPullDownController is a full project code of the video ;)